# Creating an array of objects from separate arrays of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've been trying to create an array of user objects from separate arrays of potential values. The first array is a list of users, all subsequent arrays are properties that I want associated with each user

Given these sample arrays:

```
const arr1 = [user1, user2, user3, user4]
const arr2 = [name, age, dob, etc] //for user 1
const arr3 = [name, age] // for user 2
const arr4 = []
const arr5 = [name]
```

to transform them to look like

```
[{
username: "user1",
properties: [name, age, dob, etc]
},
{
username: "user2",
properties: [name, age]
},
{
username: "user3",
properties: []
},
{
username: "user4",
properties: [name]
}]
```

Is this doable or am I taking the wrong approach trying to associate these sets of data

Comment: It's doable using something like `const [username] = arr2; users.push({username, properties: arr2}`, but this seems like a very strange way to be getting data. At some point your app should have that object already. How are you getting user info?

Comment: @CharlesBamford right, I agree that ideally I would just be getting this straight from the backend but it isn't there. So I'm grabbing all users and then making another call to get the properties from each user

Comment: You should be putting the list together as you go instead of assigning all the bits into different variables. I put together a fiddle here that demonstrates what I'm thinking. https://jsfiddle.net/c59jdgm4/ It assumes your app uses async/await.

Comment: I will try this! I am using async await

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map`:

```js
const arr1 = ["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"];
const arr2 = ["Helen", 15, "01-01-2006"];
const arr3 = ["John", 31];
const arr4 = [];
const arr5 = ["Carla"];

let result = [arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5].map((properties, i) =>
    ({ username: arr1[i], properties })
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way.

```js
const arr1 = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4']
const arr2 = ['name', 'age', 'dob', 'etc'] //for user 1
const arr3 = ['name', 'age'] // for user 2
const arr4 = []
const arr5 = ['name']
const userdata = [arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5];

const userobj = arr1.map((user, index) => {
  return { username: user, properties: userdata[index]}
  
})
console.log(userobj)
```